# PHP - How to pass a global variable to a function

Tags: php, function, global

I have a function that populates an array that was created before the function is launched. To make the population work, I used 'global' in my function. Everything is working fine with the here below situation:

```
$parameter = 'something';  
$listOne = array();

my_function($parameter);

function my_function($para) {
     global $listeOne;
     ...some code  
     $listeOne[0] = 'john';
     $listeOne[1] = 'lugano';
}
```

What I would like is to pass the array that is supposed to be used in the function when calling the function. The idea would be to do something like this:

```
$parameter = 'something';  
$listOne = array();
$listTwo = array();

my_function($listOne, $parameter);
...some code
my_function($listTwo, $parameter);

function my_function($list, $para) {
     ...some code
     $list[0] = 'john';
     $list[1] = 'lugano';
}
```

In addition according to what I read, using global is maybe not the best thing to do... I saw some people using the & sign somewhere and saying it is better. But I don't get it and not find information about that 'method'... Hope  I am clear. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's called [referencing](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php):

```
$listOne = array();

function my_function(&$list, $para) {
     ...some code
     $list[0] = 'john';
     $list[1] = 'lugano';
}
my_function($listOne, $parameter);

print_r($listOne); // array (0 => 'john', 1 => 'lugano');
```

Now the omitted array will be changed.

Comment: Helo Dan. Thanks for trying to help. How is this & sign called in that situation and how does it work? And when calling the function do I have to put the & sign as well?

Comment: @Marc: why not read the manual, he left a link to direct there

Comment: In my message `referencing` is linked, anyway the exact term for this occasion here is [Passing by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Comment: Thak you Dan. I am on my way to read what is behind that link. Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need some thing like "parameters by reference" http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 1):

Using `&` means to [pass by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

For example:

```
$x = '123';

function changeX(&$data){
   $data = '1';
}

echo $x; //x should print out as 1.
```

In your case, you could use:

```
$parameter = 'something';     
$listOne = array();   
$listTwo = array();   

my_function($listOne, $parameter);   
my_function($listTwo, $parameter);   

function my_function(&$list, $para) {   
     $list[0] = 'john';   
     $list[1] = 'lugano';   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write your function like this:

```
$listOne = array();
my_function($list = array())
{
array_push($list, 'john');
array_push($list, 'lugano');
return $list;
}  

$listOne = my_function($listOne);
print_r($listOne);
```